# Find the nth term of the recurrence relation, given the first 2 terms, f(0) and f(1)

Tags: java, c++, c++11, recursion, recurrence

f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) + f(n-1)*f(n-2);

1 <= n <= 10^9. Initial terms --> 1 <= f(0), f(1) <= 10^9.

Output the answer modulo 10^9 + 7.

The general term that I have found is, 
f(n) = (((1 + f(1))^T(n)) * ((1 + f(0))^T(n-1))) - 1;
Here T(n) is the nth Fibonacci number.

I use matrix exponentiation and modular power to solve the problem, but it gives TLE.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the problems you have? What have you tried? How did or didn't your attempt work? And what language are you programming in? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You might need to use Fermat's little theorem.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you haven't provided a sample of your code, I will give you a general idea.

Personally I wouldn't use recursion because `n` can be large thus leading to inefficient and long calculations filling stack and cause an overflow. So better inplement a cycle using array.

Next tip is to keep numbers relatively small, computing modulo on each step. `(a+b+ab)%m` is equal to `(a%m + b%m + (a%m)*(b%m))%m` (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)) so that we keep our numbers in range `0..10^9`

Here is an example of solution:

```
const unsigned int mod = 1e9+7;
std::vector<unsigned int> vec(n+1);    // prepare vector of needed size
                                       // size is n+1 because we start from 0 and you need vec[n]
vec[0] = 1;                            
vec[1] = 1e9;

unsigned long long int r1, r2;         // long long will prevent r1*r2 from overflowing
for (unsigned int i = 2; i <= n; ++i)
{
    r1 = vec[i-1] % mod;
    r2 = vec[i-2] % mod;
    vec[i] = (r1 + r2 + r1*r2) % mod;
}

std::cout << vec[n];
```

You tagged your question with [c++] and [java]. Above code is in [c++] and I hope you would be able to port it if you need

Answer (score 1):

k=1000000007 is prime.  So `a^b mod k` is equivalent to `a^(b mod (k-1))`.

mod k, f(0)+1 is 2 and f(1)+1 is -6.

Raising things to powers can be efficiently done by repeated squaring and selecting squares to multiply together.

Calculating the nth Fibbonacci mod 1000000006 is tricky (for large n).  I'm unaware of a simple closed form.

Aha!  The Pisano period is the period over which the Fibbonnacci numbers mod some value repeat.  k is decomposed into primes 2 * 500,000,003

Simply calculate the [Pisano period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period) of 2 and 500000003.  Take the LCM of the pisano period of those two primes to get the pisano period of their product.  We can use this to reduce the value n modulo this number before feeding it to Fibbonnacci.

This gives us a bounded Fibbonnacci calculation (hopefully tractible), to get us the Fibbonnacci result mod 1000000006, which we can then use the square technique (mod 1000000007) to raise 2 and -6 to that power, add them together and subtract 1.

Good luck calculating the Pisano period.  If it is reasonable (and most look to be), you should be able to take a billion-digit n and solve in a fraction of a second.

Now, the Pisano period and closed forms of Fibbonnacci is based off some number theory and math.  So instead we could try to directly generate a similar number theory/etc result for this recurrance relation rather than going through the identity you found.  Arguably that wouod be harder, but might result in a cleaner answer.